nextFocus() does not work if new value is the same as old value
I have a flutter textformfield that changes focus to the next form field so long as the new value that is being entered is different then the current value.  If I type the same value as the current value, onChanged isn't called. How can I force it to change to the next field.
EDIT: for clarity, a value appears in the textformfield when the screen is loaded.
Here is my textFormField
                            child: TextFormField(
                              autofocus: false,
                              controller: oneController,
                              onTap: () {
                                oneController.selection =
                                    TextSelection(
                                        baseOffset: 0,
                                        extentOffset:
                                        oneController.value.text.length);
                              },
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                if (value.length == 1) {
                                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                                  twoController.selection = TextSelection(
                                      baseOffset: 0,
                                      extentOffset:
                                          twoController.value.text.length);
                                }
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              maxLength: 1,
                              showCursor: false,
                              enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  counterText: "",
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                              //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),

